# PyQt4 - How to Dynamically adjust the size of Qt Layouts

Tags: pyqt4

So what I have been trying to do, is to generate a list of widgets, adding them to a grid layout, and then add them to a tab and present to the user. The problem I am having right now is that the grid layout spans the whole page per tab, but I don't have that many rows to add, so the rows ended up spanning the entire page and would not align to the top.
I tried setting alignment and verticalSpacing, but none of it changed how the widgets were displayed.

Ex:

I want the widgets displayed as the following:

```
WidgetName WidgetLabel 
WidgetName WidgetLabel     
WidgetName WidgetLabel 
WidgetName WidgetLabel
```

Instead, I am getting this:

```
WidgetName WidgetLabel


WidgetName WidgetLabel 


WidgetName WidgetLabel


WidgetName WidgetLabel
```

Is there a way to force all elements to the top or in any direction desired?

Answer (score 5):

A layout is going to take the full space allowed of its parent widget by default. What I would  typically do is place the grid within another layout and add some stretch to the end.

```py
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        # you can directly control the spacing here
        grid.setSpacing(20)

        for row in xrange(5):
            grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Text"), row, 0, 
                1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
            grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel(str(row)), row, 1, 
                1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        mainLayout.addLayout(grid)
        mainLayout.addStretch()
```

The stretch will eat up all the rest of the available space and squash the grid up to the top.  The benefit of doing this, is you do not have to add anything else abnormal to the grid itself. The stretch is part of the parent layout.

Now the `setSpacing` will give you the fine control of pushing space back into the items.

Comment: This method totally helped. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to hit the check mark if this solved the question!